# Expression "shockingly enough"

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

Is the expression *shockingly enough* an understatement?

I've heard of *oddly enough* and took it to mean *to some extent, it's odd*, but the combination of *shockingly* and *enough* sounds like you are trying to convey an understatement, or what one would use in the negative, like

> It's not shocking enough to merit any interest.

Comment: I'm not following. Your example does not use the expression in question. Please clarify.

Answer (score 7):

While *oddly enough* is used most often to introduce something that is counterintuitive (and much less often in an ironic sense), I have only very rarely heard or seen *shockingly enough* used outside of a context similar to this:

> Shockingly enough, Albanian is spoken mostly in Albania.

That use can be described as "ironic" in much the same way as a [TI class supertanker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_class_supertankers) can be described as "sort of a large canoe". Far from indicating any degree of shock, the phrase is most often used to point out the blindingly obvious.

That is not to say that it is *never* used in a literal sense. When it is used without irony, it is not usually an understatement:

> Shockingly enough, most of the actual violence is carried out by school-age children and not by the veterans of the gang because of laws limiting the sentences of juvenile offenders.

In both phrases, *enough* is probably superfluous, but it is idiomatic, particularly when the phrase is used ironically.

Comment: I'll go with this and delete my own answer. Excellent examples, both.

Comment: I would expect the enough portion to link an additional statement. Like _ Albanian is a slavic language originating in Eastern europe. OR _ Members of gang xyz is believed to be responsible for over 100 deaths already this year.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't. *Enough* doesn't imply *wait -- there's more!*